# How a make a button with physics?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I want to make a button and press it with a hand in blender with physics. I know I can do it with Keyframes in timeline, but I want to make a reusable button so I can create a lot of button which can be pressed in future animation.

My idea is to add a spring to the bottom of the button and linked to the box. So when I press it, it rebounds back to the original location.

However, I find it doesn't work as expected. I find I have several problems.

1. I can't limit the button movement in only one axis level (like z-axis)
2. I can't limit the spring movement too
3. The button move out of the box after it is pushing my the spring
4. I don't know if using spring is a good idea as its movement is not that good. The button is shaking.

Hope anyone can share some experience and advice to me. Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: a real world button has a lip to stop the button coming out the top and a peg to stop the button being depressed to far. All that said, I would look at rigging this with an armature/bones, rather than physics and a spring.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will go for rigging to make a new try. But if i want to make a hand pressing the button. It is going to be two part - movement of hand and movement of the button. Is it the way you mean in setting up this animation ?

Comment: Finally I made the change and add "Transformation" constraint to the button with a control mesh. So i can use the control mesh to control the movement of the button.